# Prolog stuck on a complex predicate

Tags: prolog

i'm stuck on a timetable clash question. Given these rules, I need to see if there is a student that is enrolled in two separate classes that has a class on the same day and time using the the predicate clash/1.

```
student(alice).
student(bob).
student(claire).
student(don).

enrolled(alice, logic).
enrolled(alice, maths).
enrolled(bob, maths).
enrolled(claire, physics).
enrolled(don, logic).
enrolled(don, art_history).

class(logic, monday, 10).
class(logic, wednesday, 10).
class(maths, tuesday, 14).
class(maths, thursday, 14).
class(physics, wednesday, 10).
class(physics, friday, 14).
class(art_history, monday, 10).
class(art_history, friday, 10).
```

Currently I have this:

```
clash(Student):- enrolled(Student, X), enrolled(Student, Y),
    class(X, A, B), class(Y, C, D), A = C, B = D.
```

But I can't get it to work, any suggestions on solving this or guidance on if i'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to state that the classes need to be different.
This can be easily added:

```
clash(Student):- enrolled(Student, X), enrolled(Student, Y), X\=Y,
    class(X, A, B), class(Y, C, D), A = C, B = D.
```

Comment: Wow, you're right. Such a simple oversight, thank you so much. One question though, do you think there is a way to simplify this?

Comment: clash(Student):- enrolled(Student, X), enrolled(Student, Y), X\=Y,
    class(X, A, B), class(Y, A, B).

Comment: And I would prefer more descriptive variables like:  clash(Student):- enrolled(Student, Class1), enrolled(Student, Class2), Class1\=Class2, class(Class1, Day, Time), class(Class2, Day, Time).